# C# query, how to add in the list

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a database query whare I will only need the Id and the name of an organization, how can I do that?

```
var orgList = new List<OrganizationModel>();
var organization = await dbContext.Organization
    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == xlOrganization);

orgList.Add(organization); // this gives an error
```

Error: Cannot convert from '<anonymous type: int Id, string Name> to 'OrganizationModel'

I dont need any other columns aside from the name and the Id, how can I fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, this:

```cs
new { x.Id, x.Name }
```

creates an instance of an anonymous type. What else did you think that `new` on its own would do? If you want instances of the `OrganizationModel` type then that's what you need to create:

```cs
new OrganizationModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }
```